# How to permanently skip a package dependency installation in Brew

Tags: install, homebrew, upgrade, python

How can I make Brew skip attempting to install Python@3.9 during `brew upgrade`?  I have Python@3.8.7 already set globally.

BACKGROUND: I'm running High Sierra 10.13.6, and at this time, Brew is attempting to install Python@3.9 via make. It continues to stall for even some days with three processes taking six threads. My only option is to quit it every time, but then I cannot continue with `brew upgrade`.

Comment: What does “brew reinstall python” do?

Comment: Goes through a list: setuptools-52.0.0.tar.gz, pip-21.0.1.tar.gz, wheel-0.36.2.tar.gz, and then finally Python-3.9.1.tar.xz to which I Ctrl-C.